# calculate basis for the orthogonal column space

Tags: linear-algebra

Give a basis for  $(Col(A))\bot$ where $A$ is defined as follows:

$A =\begin{pmatrix}-1&3&1\\ 2&2&1\\0&8&3\end{pmatrix} -> \begin{pmatrix}1&0&1/8\\ 0&1&3/8\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

My plan:

- put matrix in a row reduced echelon form and create a basis for the nullspace:

$basis = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\-3\\8 \end{pmatrix}$

- Then I wanted to find a vector that is orthogonal and has no 0 in it.
  I was thinking of $basis\bot = \begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

this is apparently not a good way.

can someone help me and explain to me what steps I have to make.
i choose for this one because $basis \cdot basis\bot = 0$

the given answer for this question is:$\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}$

answer from the professor ( this question is an exam question):
[image]

Comment: You start by saying "put matrix in a row reduced echelon form" but you do NOT do that!  Why?

Comment: i did that on paper, ill add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ cannot be $0$-dimensional ($A\neq0$) and it cannot be $1$-dimensional (that would happen only if the columns were all a multiple of the same vector), $\dim\operatorname{Col}(A)=2$ or $\dim\operatorname{Col}(A)=3$. But $\det A=0$ and therefore we cannot have $\dim\operatorname{Col}(A)=3$. So, $\dim\operatorname{Col}(A)=2$.

We can try to write the third column as a linear combination of the other two:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-a+3b=1\\2a+2b=1\\8b=3.\end{array}\right.$$And this works: you can take $a=\frac18$ and $b=\frac38$. So, $\operatorname{Col}(A)=\operatorname{span}\left\{(-1,2,0)^T,(3,2,8)^T\right\}$, and therefore$$\operatorname{Col}(A)^\perp=\operatorname{span}\left\{(-1,2,0)^T\times(3,2,8)^T\right\}=\operatorname{span}\left\{(16,8,-8)^T\right\}.$$

Comment: can you explain one more thing for me? Someone else said i could use the following: $(col(A))\bot = Nul(A\bot)$. how does this work?

Comment: I don't even understand what that means. Perhaps that you could post it as a new question.

Comment: i added the solution of my professor to my post. what can you say about this?

Comment: Your professor wrote $A^T$, not $A^\perp$. It's a fine answer. And his or her final answer is identical to mine.

Comment: I don't entirely understand it.  Col(A)=span{(−1,2,0)T,(3,2,8)T} is also equal to the basis if i am correct? then why Col(A) has 2 vectors and when you calculate the orthogonal only 1?

Comment: SInce $\dim\mathbb R^3=3$ and $\dim\operatorname{Col}(A)=2$, $\dim\operatorname{Col}(A)^\perp=3-2=1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97052/discussion-between-marco-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Answer (score 1):

Your original idea doesn’t quite work because the null space of a matrix doesn’t in general have any particular relation to its column space. That’s more obvious when the matrix isn’t square, say $n\times m$ with $n\ne m$: the null space is a subset of an $m$-dimensional space, but the column space is a subset of an $n$-dimensional space.

Recall that the null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its *row* space. Thus, what you really did was to find an element of $A$’s row space. What you need to do instead, then, is to find a basis for the null space of $A^T$.